# how to make sure random number generation with equal probability?

Tags: java, random

```
   Random r1 = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.print(r1.nextInt(10) + " ");
    }
```

output for one run:
9 7 6 8 3 5 3 3 0 4

why isn't 0-9 generated with equal probability? 3 alone occurs three times, but 1 & 2 zero times.

Comment: try a larger sample size

Comment: theoretically speaking there is equal probability. Practice is always something else ;) Also, the numbers are pseudorandom, not truly random so that affects it a bit ;)

Comment: Let's say you toss a coin twice, and get the same result each time. Would you say that the two faces of the coin don't have the same probability of occurring? If you need every value to occur exactly once, then create an array, flush it, and iterate over it.

Comment: If you'd have each number once, predetermined, that wouldn't be random at all.

Comment: Because in terms of coins you are flipping the coin 10 times, don't be surprised if you get 10 heads or 10 tails, that is an unequal distribution but with equal probability. If you want your distribution to look like the probability distribution you need A LOT of samples (or coin flips).

Answer (score 5):

Empirical probability is not the same as theoretical probability. What you see is the fact that in *this* case you got 3 3's and no 2's. If you were to run this again, you would get a different set. You would approach the theoretical probability as the number of runs increases.

As others mention, is tossing a coin twice and getting heads both times a sign that the coin is flawed or has an absurd probability of heads? No. If you tossed it a few million times and got all heads? That's a bit more likely then.

Comment: Is there a way to guarantee random generation with equal probability?

Comment: @lingvisa `java.util.Random` does that, in the same way that a coin or die does.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, did you see my code? it's indeed Java.util.Random.

Comment: @lingvisa That's what we're trying to tell you. It *is* equal probability, based on a mathematical definition of that word.

Comment: @lingvisa Can you explain exactly what it is that you want? It would seem that it is not random numbers in a range with equal probability, so what _is_ it?

Comment: @hexafraction & Boris: I want to split a file with multiple lines. The split ratio is for instance 4:5. For 100 lines, 40 goes to one file and 50 to another file. And the split must be random.

Comment: @lingvisa Looks like you want a shuffle where 40 left most elements go to file A and rest to B

Answer (score 2):

If you want to randomize the order of the elements (0-9), you are likely looking for something like a [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle).

For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i = values.length; i > 0; i--) {
    int index = random.nextInt(i);
    int i1 = values[index];
    int i2 = values[i - 1];

    values[i - 1] = i1;
    values[index] = i2;
}
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, `Collections.suffle` is a Fisher Yates implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't want random numbers, but a shuffled list of numbers (like a deck of 52 cards).

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
Collections.shuffle(list);
// now display them. They will appear in random order, each exactly once
for (Integer i : list) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: shffule is another way for randomization? probably it uses random() behind the scene.

Comment: Read the javadoc, or the sources, and you'll find out.

Comment: Using Random isn't the problem.  It's how you use its results.

Answer (score 0):

From, the OP's comment the requirement becomes more clear:

> I want to split a file with multiple lines. The split ratio is for
>   instance 4:5. For 100 lines, 40 goes to one file and 50 to another
>   file. And the split must be random

So random numbers are not required, what is required is a random order of numbers `1` to `numLines`.

This will fulfil the requirement:

```
public List<Integer> randomLines(final int numLines) {
    final List<Integer> lineNumbers = new ArrayList<>(100);
    //put the line numbers into the List
    //each line occurs exactly once
    for (int i = 1; i <= numLines; ++i) {
        lineNumbers.add(i);
    }
    final Random random = new Random();
    //Carry out a random reording of the List
    Collections.shuffle(lineNumbers, random);
    return lineNumbers;
}
```

In order to test this code I created a simple test case:

1. Pick a random split point
2. Create two `Set<Integer.` for the line numbers of each file
3. Verify that the `Set`s have size `splitPoint` and `numLines - splitPoint`

This works because a `Set` can only contain unique items so if there were duplicates then the `Set`s would have the wrong size:

```
@Test
public void testRandomLines() {
    final App app = new App();
    final List<Integer> lineNumbers = app.randomLines(100);
    //pick a random split point
    final int splitPoint = random.nextInt(lineNumbers.size());
    System.out.println(splitPoint);
    final Set<Integer> firstFile = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    final Set<Integer> secondFile = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lineNumbers.size(); ++i) {
        if (i < splitPoint) {
            firstFile.add(lineNumbers.get(i));
        } else {
            secondFile.add(lineNumbers.get(i));
        }
    }
    assertThat(firstFile.size(), is(splitPoint));
    assertThat(secondFile.size(), is(lineNumbers.size() - splitPoint));
}
```

I hope this answers your question.